# Getting bad results to form field formula Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, forms, field-codes

I am using Word 2007 and have a form with "Filling in forms" protection.

I have a formula field: `{[FormText { =Round(Price/0.5, 2)}}]` that shows like this: `100.00`. The `[]` brackets indicate a bookmark named `Pmt`.

Another form field: `{ =Pmt \# "0.00" }` shows `100100.00` which is a problem. If my first field shows `100.00` then why does the second show `100100.00` and what can I do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are picking up both the formatted and unformatted figures because your bookmark spans the entire form field.

Instead try to use the built-in bookmark functionality of a form field:

[image]

Comment: Huh?!? That's weird but I can't think of a better explanation. Anyway I tried your idea (deleted the bookmark and entered the bookmark in the form field) and got the same thing. Then I did it the other way around: deleted the bookmark and recreated it by simply selecting the form field and clicking Bookmark > Add Bookmark and then it worked.